# Styling background of several words in one TextView element

Tags: android

What is the fastest way to set background color for multiple separate words in TextView? Those TextView elements will end up as rows in a long ListView so I need most optimal way to do it.

Should I try to use Spannable to style TextView element backgrounds or just replace ListView with WebView? Maybe there are any other options?

Comment: You mean replace listview item(the text view) with webview or replace the whole Listview with webview?

Comment: Replace whole ListView with WebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView has a performance problem, I mean it's slow. TextView can also take simple html tags. It doesn't support the whole she bang so you'd have to check. In my opinion, spannable was invented for this purpose only.